# Detect UIScrollview scrolling past bottom

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview, uiscrollviewdelegate

I'm trying to create functionality similar to Reeder where you are introduced to new content if you scroll below or above the content in a scroll view.

I thought I was heading in a good place with scrollViewWillEndDragging:withVelocity:targetContentOffset:

However, this just stops at the bottom.

Is there any way to detect if you are scrolling beyond the bottom or top (this is when the vertical scrollbar begins to get smaller)

Thanks!

Comment: why dont you check the contentOffset in scrollviewDidScroll and the moment the contet offset is beyond your bottom/top point, add new stuff to the scrollview, and increase the content size

Comment: That is the trick. I solved it by getting a value of contentOffset - scrollview content size - scrollview height :  float diff = scrollView.contentOffset.y -(scrollView.contentSize.height- scrollView.frame.size.height);
    if(diff>30){
     //do what needs to be done
    }

Answer (score 4):

posting comment as answer:

Check the `contentOffset` in `scrollviewDidScroll` and the moment the `contetOffset` is beyond your bottom/top point, add new stuff to the scrollview, and increase the content size

Answer (score 0):

Maybe better solution would be something like this:

```
-(void)scrollViewWillEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withVelocity:(CGPoint)velocity targetContentOffset:(inout CGPoint *)targetContentOffset {

    if (targetContentOffset->y == 0 && scrollView.contentOffset.y < - someOffset) { //use someOffset if you dont want to reload immedeately on scroll to top
        //dragged past top
    }

    if (targetContentOffset->y == scrollView.contentSize.height && scrollView.contentOffset.y > scrollView.contentSize.height + someOffset) { 
        //dragged past bottom
    }

}
```